# Sorting IPv4 address with port number

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to alter an IP address string that has a port number in it so to sort a table, an example IP string:

```
 IP = "120.88.66.99:075"
```

I can remove the `.`'s and the `:` with:

```
 IP = string.gsub(IP,'%W',"")
```

and that gives me `120886699075` but I would like to change the only `:` to a `.` so it gives me `120886699.075`

Edit:

Actually what I wanted is not working as it does not take in to account the number of numbers between the .'s so what I woulds like is a way to sort the ip in the given format so a table containing the original ip string can be sorted.

Edit 2:

I have this nearly working with this:

```
 function IPToDec(IPs)
  local t = {}
  local f = "(.-)%."
  local l = 1;
  local s, e, c = IPs:find(f,1)
  while s do
    if s ~= 1 or c ~= "" then
     table.insert(t,c)
    end
    l = e+1;
    s, e, c = IPs:find(f,l)
  end
  if l <= #IPs then
    c = IPs:sub(l)
    table.insert(t,c)
  end
  if(#t == 4) then
    return 16777216*t[1] + 65536*t[2] + 256*t[3] + t[4]
  else
    return -1
  end
 end

 IP = "120.88.66.99:075"
 IP = IPToDec(IP:gsub('%:+'..'%w+',""))
```

but I'm having to loose the port to get it to sort properly, ideally I would like to include the port number in the sorting because it might be possible that the ip's are coming from the same source but different computers.

Comment: Why do you need to sort a table? Lua tables can be indexed directly with anything you like. Perhaps you can ask a separate question.

Comment: Well I have a table of ip strings that populates a listview control so I want to sort the table ascending and descending to then make the listview control sort.

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: why? the fact the ip string is a table element is irrelevant as its still a string.

Comment: Is your edit only trying to explain the background, or asking how to solve the sorting problem. If it's the latter, as lhf said, ask a separate question.

Comment: Just the background, I have the sorting working its just getting the ip string in the correct format that I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution is to use two patterns:

```
IP = IP:gsub("%.", ""):gsub(":", ".")
```

The first `gsub` replaces `.` with an empty string, the second one replaces `:` to `.`

---

Using one call to `gsub` is also possible. Use an auxiliary table as the second argument like this:

```
 IP = IP:gsub("%W", {["."] = "", [":"] = "."})
```

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
IP1 = "120.88.11.1:075"
IP2 = "120.88.1.11:075"
```

will be converted to the same string `12088111.075`
Is this what you really need?

Probably, you want the following type of conversion?

```
IP1 = "120.88.11.1:075" --> 120088011001.075
IP2 = "120.88.1.11:075" --> 120088001011.075
```

---

```
local function IPToDec(IPs)
   -- returns integer from (-1) to (2^48-1)
   local d1, d2, d3, d4, port = IPs:match'^(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+):?(%d+)$'
   if d1 then
      port = port == '' and 0 or port
      return (((d1*256+d2)*256+d3)*256+d4)*65536+port
   else
      return -1
   end
end

print(string.format('%.16g',IPToDec("120.88.66.99:075")))
print(string.format('%.16g',IPToDec("120.88.66.99")))
print(string.format('%.16g',IPToDec("not an IP")))
```

Comment: Good comment, but it's not an answer, so not supposed to be posted here.

Comment: @YuHao - Do not have enough rep to post comments yet :-)

Comment: Egor, could you do something to your name to distinguish it from the other Egor Skriptunoff who has 10k rep: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff. Or are you the same person =:P

Comment: @Schollii - Both logins are mine.  This is my second login for using SO from work.