# List of Comparators in Sorting Networks

Tags: algorithm, list, comparator, sorting-network

I have a question in my homework document, and I'm having hard to time to visualize and understand the question. Question is the following:

> We can represent an n-input comparison network with c comparators as a
>   list of c pairs of integers in the range from 1 to n. If two pairs
>   contain an integer in common, the order of the corresponding
>   comparators in the network is determined by the order of the pairs in
>   the list. Given this representation, describe an O(n + c)-time
>   (serial) algorithm for determining the depth of a comparison network.

What does it mean to have pairs of integers in the context of comparison networks? Normally we used the notation below for denoting a comparison network where each horizontal line represents a number.

[image]

Comment: (2,3) means there's a comparator between line 2 and line 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that if you have a pair (1, 2), that's one of those vertical lines, namely the one that connects horizontal lines 1 and 2.

So the top left part of this picture would be represented as (1, 2) (3, 4) (1, 3) (2, 4).

[image: top left part]

The depth of just that part is 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But one more thing; how should I know that (1,2) and (3,4) is parallel just by looking at the numbers? They could also be serial in somewhere else in the whole network, right?

Comment: Also, the part "If two pairs contain an integer in common, the order of the corresponding comparators in the network is determined by the order of the pairs in the list." means that if there are (1,2) and (1,3) as in your answer, they should be in an order same as in the picture. Am I right?

Comment: @MertToka yes. The thing that happens is that a partial order is induced by those constraints, so (1, 2) and (3, 4) *might* be ordered, for example if you put a (1, 3) *in between* which would be ordered with both of them. In the example here, (1, 2) and (3, 4) are unordered because 1) they have nothing in common and 2) there's nothing in between that orders them implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i = 1, n 
  depth[i] = 0

total_depth = 0
for j = 1, c
  i1 = comparators[j].entry1
  i2 = comparators[j].entry2
  new_depth = 1 + max(depth[i1], depth[i2])
  depth[i1] = new_depth
  depth[i2] = new_depth
  total_depth = max(total_depth, new_depth)

print(total_depth)
```

Comment: Don't you have an account with 10k rep? What's up with this extra one?

Comment: @harold - Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654734/sorting-ipv4-address-with-port-number/23654950#comment36337301_23654950)